What does it mean for some functions and relationships can only be used inside integrals?
When I am studyinig differential equations, lecture notes said "by fundalmental theorem of Calculus”, we have
$$
\frac{{\rm d}\operatorname{H}\left(x\right)}{{\rm d}x}=\delta \left(x\right)
$$
but such functions and relationships can only be used inside integrals.
I am not sure what does it mean "inside integrals" and I cannot think of any examples.
Thanks for answering !!!.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Start by reading about the Dirac delta function at this wikipedia page and some of the links there https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function , particularly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)

The main point is that $\delta(x)$ isn't really a function of $x$. (What is $\delta(0)$?) But integrals of $\delta(x)$ times a smooth function can be defined even though $\delta(x)$ can't.  $\int\delta(x)f(x),dx= f(0)$ (provided the integration is over an interval that contains $0$). So the remark you quoted essentially means: Use $\delta(x)$ only in contexts where it makes sense.

It is not a function, actually.

It's not completely true that those "functions" and relationships can only be used inside integrals.
However, distributions like $\delta$ act on functions in an integral-like way. Abusing integral notation, we define $\delta$ by
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx=\varphi(0),$$
and we define the distributional derivative $Df$ of a function $f$ by
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} Df(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx
=-\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,\varphi'(x)\,dx.
$$
Here $\varphi$ is a nicely behaving function; it's infinitely differentiable and vanishing outside a bounded region.
Using these two definitions we can show that $DH=\delta$:
$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} DH(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx
= -\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H(x)\,\varphi'(x)\,dx
= -\int_{0}^{\infty} \varphi'(x)\,dx
\\
= -\left[ \varphi(x) \right]_{0}^{\infty}
= \varphi(0)
= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)\,\varphi(x)\,dx
$$
valid for all such nicely behaving $\varphi$ and therefore implying $DH=\delta$ as distributions.
